# Ionic 2 app update - Permission model downgrade

Tags: android, ionic2

When I upload my app update to the play store, it gives me this warning:

```
Permission model downgrade

PROBLEM
Users that have the APK with version code 1201, which targets SDK 23 or higher, will receive an error when they attempt to upgrade to this APK because it targets SDK 22.

RESOLUTION
Ensure that your release includes APKs targeting SDK 23 or higher to which all users that have the APK with version code 1201 can upgrade.
My old version has a target SDK of 24.
```

I’ve set the `android-targetSdkVersion` to 26 in `config.xml` and running `ionic cordova build android --release` is successful but somewhere along the build process, Gradle overwrites the target SDK value in the Android Manifest and sets it to 22.

What do I need to do to have gradle set the target SDK value to 24 or higher?

Below is my ionic info result:

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 
local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
ios-deploy        : 1.9.2 
Node              : v6.9.2
npm               : 4.0.5 
OS                : macOS High Sierra
Xcode             : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b 
Environment Variables:

ANDROID_HOME : /Users/esthonwood/Library/Android/sdk
Misc:

backend : pro
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the culprit is the `cordova-plugin-googlemaps` plugin that I use. They have a `build-extras.gradle` file that sets the `targetSdkVersion` to 22. I reinstalled the plugin and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The same happended to me....Seems that Google wants to protect the existing users who installed the APP with SK version 16 on their devices...

I have lost more than 18 hours trying to figure out what to do, but I found nothing.

The olnly thing I have found was to UNPUBLISH THE APP (HIDE) and go again to the whole process OF CREATING A NEW APP...I am devastated since I lost all my graphic material required to creating a new APP....

GOOGLE FU*CK YOU